# C++ Fraction Calculator

Tags: c++

This is a C++ program to add, subtract, multiply, or divide fractions. My program has no error with the compiler, but when I run it, I enter a choice from the menu and immediately get the output "The answer is: -2/1409189243." Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Any help is appreciated. I am a beginner.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int menu (int);
int addFractions(int, int, int, int, int, int);
int subtractFractions(int, int, int, int, int, int);
int multiplyFractions(int, int, int, int, int, int);
int divideFractions(int, int, int, int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int operation;
    int n1, d1, n2, d2, n3, d3;

    menu(operation);

    if (operation == 1)
        addFractions(n1, d1, n2, d2, n3, d3);
    if (operation == 2)
        subtractFractions(n1, d1, n2, d2, n3, d3);
    if (operation == 3)
        multiplyFractions(n1, d1, n2, d2, n3, d3);
    if (operation == 4)
        divideFractions(n1, d1, n2, d2, n3, d3);


    cout << "The answer is: " << n3 << "/" << d3;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}

int menu(int operation)
{
    cout << "This program allows the user to enter two fractions and perform";
    cout << " one of four \n arithmetic operations: addition, subtraction, ";
    cout << "multiplication, division. Please decide which operation you ";
    cout << "would like to perform. Enter '1' to add, '2' to \n subtract, '3' ";
    cout << "to multiply, or '4' to divide. \n";
    cin >> operation;
    cout << endl;

    return operation;
}

int addFractions(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int n3, int d3)
{
    cout << "Enter 2 fractions to be divided. Enter one integer at a time, ";
    cout << "each divided by a space. First, enter numerator 1, then";
    cout << " denominator 1, followed by numerator 2, then denominator 2.";
    cin >> n1 >> d1 >> n2 >> d2;
    cout << endl;

    n3 = ((n1*d2) + (n2*d1)) / (d1* d2);
    d3 = d1 * d2;

    return n3, d3;

}

int subtractFractions(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int n3, int d3)
{
    cout << "Enter 2 fractions to be divided. Enter one integer at a time, ";
    cout << "each divided by a space. First, enter numerator 1, then";
    cout << " denominator 1, followed by numerator 2, then denominator 2.";
    cin >> n1 >> d1 >> n2 >> d2;
    cout << endl;

    n3 = (n1*d2) - (n2*d1);
    d3 = d1 * d2;

    return n3, d3;
}

int multiplyFractions(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int n3, int d3)
{
    cout << "Enter 2 fractions to be divided. Enter one integer at a time, ";
    cout << "each divided by a space. First, enter numerator 1, then";
    cout << " denominator 1, followed by numerator 2, then denominator 2.";
    cin >> n1 >> d1 >> n2 >> d2;
    cout << endl;

    n3 = n1 * n2;
    d3 = d1 * d2;

    return n3, d3;
}

int divideFractions(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int n3, int d3)
{
    cout << "Enter 2 fractions to be divided. Enter one integer at a time, ";
    cout << "each divided by a space. First, enter numerator 1, then";
    cout << " denominator 1, followed by numerator 2, then denominator 2.";
    cin >> n1 >> d1 >> n2 >> d2;
    cout << endl;

    n3 = n1 * d2;
    d3 = n2 * d1;

    return n3, d3;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your full code. Trim it down to exactly what causes the problem -- in this case, I doubt you need your actual math code, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do `return n3, d3;`. If you declare the function as `int foo(...` it must return a single `int`.

If your first 4 parameters are inputs, and the last two are outputs, change the function to

```
int subtractFractions(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int& n3, int& d3)
```

Notice the last two parameters are passed by reference instead of by value. So if they are modified within the function, the modified value will be reflected back outside of the function.

Also if a function returns a value, you should use an assignment to get that variable back.

```
int menu()
{
    int oper;
    // get operation from user
    return oper
}
```

Then later

```
int operation = menu();  // call the function and get return value
```

Comment: What should I do instead of returning n3 and d3? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You can change the function to `void subtract...(`, then change those last two parameters to be passed by reference as I showed above (by adding a `&`).